# Why the information I submited to Google for verify OAuth is failed?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I submitted my information to Google APIs to verify OAuth, but google inform to me that my verification step is failed (message: Failed verification (Last approved consent screen is still in use)). I don't know which of my information has problem.

I checked my information, there are two possible information that might be the reason for this issue:

1. Scopes for Google APIs: in this part, I received the warning:"Because you've added a sensitive scope, your consent screen requires verification by Google before it's published."
   In this part I only added 1 value:https://mail.google.com/, other default value is "email", "profile", "openid".
2. Authorized domains: in this part, I also receive the same warning from google as (1),
   In this part I only add 1 value: XXX.com.au

I don't know which part is the real reason for this issue. Anyone has done this step, please help me or give me some guide for this.